# How to edit an entry on condition in macro in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, macros, ms-access-2007

I need make a macro to take data from a table and add it to another table.

I have the following table (Sum of passed classes):

```
 _______|Student|________|Class|_______|Number of Times Class Was Passed|__
         Johnny           A             5
         Johnny           C             3
         David            A             2
         David            C             4
```

And I need to fill up the table below (Students and number of times they passed a class):

```
_______|Student|________|# of Times Passed A |_______|# of Times Passed C|__
        Johnny
        David
```

How would I go about creating a macro to fill the above table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in a query.

Make 3 derived queries:

1. with all the unique students
2. filtered result of the table with Class = A
3. filtered result of the table with Class = C

take query 1 and left join query 2 and query 3 to it. This combined query can be used to insert the values in the new table.